# oreilly multipartrequest class to upload multiple images

Tags: java

i am using oreilly multipartrequest class to upload multiple images, images are getting uploaded fine , but i want to know the name of all the images uploaded per request.

i am  trying to print all filename using the below but it is printing the name of the last file only. I am trying to upload files 1.jpg , 2.jpg , 3.jpg , but it is printing only 3.jpg , what should i modify in the code to make it print all names.:

```
MultipartRequest m = new MultipartRequest(request, "C:/Users/;
      Enumeration files = m.getFileNames();

        while (files.hasMoreElements()) {

            String name = (String) files.nextElement();
            filename = m.getFilesystemName(name);
            System.out.println(filename);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also list the files by making a file with the directory you wish to list.

```
   File dir = new File(directory);
for (File f : dir.listFiles()){
System.out.print(f.getName());
}
```

Hope this helps

For more refernce check this link:

[Oracle reference on File class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)